# get a static src from json returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm trying to build an overlay that shows two images. the images `src` is stored in a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "title": "Multimilionario",
        "front": "http://placehold.it/810x2028?text=front",
        "back": "http://placehold.it/810x2028?text=back"
    }]
}
```

when i click on a button, the overlay opens and it's supposed to append the src to two `<img>`s. but what i get is `src(undefined)`.

my jquery click function looks like this (I've left off all the logic for the overlay to open/close):

```
$(".js-overlay-start").unbind("click").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/overlay.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var item = data.items;
            console.log(item);

            $('.json-front').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-back').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-front').attr("src", item.front);
            $('.json-back').attr("src", item.back);
        } //success
    });//ajax
});
```

i've used this very structure to build something very simple on another project and it worked fine. I'm not sure what's going on.

is it because the overlay is hidden or something? any hint or help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `items` is an array. Use `var item = data.items[0]` or else add a `for` loop.

Comment: it worked thanks! if you want to answer the question i'll accept yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using data.items like a single object, it's an array.

```
$(".js-overlay-start").unbind("click").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/overlay.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var item = data.items[0];
            console.log(item);

            $('.json-front').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-back').attr("src", "");
            $('.json-front').attr("src", item.front);
            $('.json-back').attr("src", item.back);
        } //success
    });//ajax
});
```